# Translation of Lookup window Text

Tags: lookup, translation, lookup-filter

When we add a lookup filter, there is an option to enter the lookup window text. Does Lookup window text automatically translate? or is there a way to translate Lookup window text?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, lookup fields do not automatically translate. Yes, you can add your own translation. First, enable translations if you haven't already, under Setup > Translation Workbench > Translation Settings, and add any languages you want to translate to/from. Then, go to Setup > Translation Workbench > Translate. Change Language to the desired language, Setup Component to Lookup Filter, change the Object to the desired object, and finally choose the Error Message or Informational Message Aspect. From there, you can translate the values as you desire. The **Informational Message** is that which is displayed in the Lookup Window, while the **Error Message** is that which is displayed when an invalid selection is made.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Much. Just now figured it out myself. Anyways thanks much for your help.